How to add circos.rect to my chordDiagram
I have been stuck trying to add rectangles with more info to my chordDiagram but I keep getting errors.
This is my code:
library(circlize)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(file = "TF_uv_chord.txt", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(file = "TF_uv_chord_lfc.txt", header = T)

cdm_res = chordDiagram(df, #col = colmat, grid.col = state_col2,
    directional = 0, annotationTrack = "grid", 
    big.gap = 20, small.gap = 1,
    preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = 0.5),
    link.target.prop = FALSE)
    
circos.track(track.index = 2, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
    xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
    ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
    sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
    xplot = get.cell.meta.data("xplot")
     
circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, CELL_META$ycenter , sector.name, facing = "bending.outside", 
            niceFacing = T, adj = c(0.5, 0.5), col= "blue", font = 2, cex = 0.6)
           
circos.axis(h="top", labels=T, labels.cex = 0.3)


}
, bg.border = NA)


So far I am getting my chorddiagram 
but I want to add log2foldchange (df2) values but my attempts have resulted in this error: Error: Please specify x:
l2_val <- as.matrix(df2$LFC) 

col_fun <- colorRamp2(c(min(l2_val),0, max(l2_val)), c("turquoise2", "white", "magenta3")) 


for(i in seq_len(nrow(cdm_res))) {  
        circos.rect(cdm_res[i, "x1"], ylim[1], 0, ylim[2], 
            col = col_fun(df2[cdm_res$rn[i], cdm_res$cn[i]]),    #col & borde same info 
            border = col_fun(df2[cdm_res$rn[i], cdm_res$cn[i]]),
            sector.index = cdm_res$rn[i], track.index = 1)

        circos.rect(cdm_res[i, "x2"], ylim[1], 0, ylim[2], 
            col = col_fun(df2[cdm_res$rn[i], cdm_res$cn[i]]), 
            border = col_fun(df2[cdm_res$rn[i], cdm_res$cn[i]]),
            sector.index = cdm_res$cn[i], track.index = 1)
     }       

Error: Please specify `x`

if anyone has any idea how to add rectangles with the df2 info, I would be very grateful.
thanks, thanks
data:
> df
     TF   treatment n
1  bZIP PARUV2.PAR2 9
2  bHLH PARUV2.PAR2 2
3  C2H2 PARUV2.PAR2 8
4   MYB PARUV2.PAR2 3
5  GATA PARUV2.PAR2 4
6   C3H PARUV2.PAR2 4
7  NFX1 PARUV2.PAR2 1
8  bZIP PARUV8.PAR2 9
9  bHLH PARUV8.PAR2 2
10 C2H2 PARUV8.PAR2 8
11  MYB PARUV8.PAR2 3
12 GATA PARUV8.PAR2 3
13  C3H PARUV8.PAR2 3
14 NFX1 PARUV8.PAR2 1
15 bZIP PARUV8.PAR8 9
16 bHLH PARUV8.PAR8 1
17 C2H2 PARUV8.PAR8 5
18  MYB PARUV8.PAR8 2
19 GATA PARUV8.PAR8 1
20  C3H PARUV8.PAR8 3
21 NFX1 PARUV8.PAR8 1
> df2
     TF   treatment  LFC
1  bZIP PARUV2.PAR2 5.35
2  bHLH PARUV2.PAR2 2.48
3  C2H2 PARUV2.PAR2 3.91
4   MYB PARUV2.PAR2 3.78
5  GATA PARUV2.PAR2 2.73
6   C3H PARUV2.PAR2 2.44
7  NFX1 PARUV2.PAR2 2.57
8  bZIP PARUV8.PAR2 3.69
9  bHLH PARUV8.PAR2 2.26
10 C2H2 PARUV8.PAR2 3.23
11  MYB PARUV8.PAR2 4.23
12 GATA PARUV8.PAR2 2.17
13  C3H PARUV8.PAR2 2.25
14 NFX1 PARUV8.PAR2 2.34
15 bZIP PARUV8.PAR8 5.66
16 bHLH PARUV8.PAR8 1.60
17 C2H2 PARUV8.PAR8 3.04
18  MYB PARUV8.PAR8 5.22
19 GATA PARUV8.PAR8 1.01
20  C3H PARUV8.PAR8 1.70
21 NFX1 PARUV8.PAR8 2.53
> 

